# Strange 'sidebar effects' associated with hiding sidebar from a button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, wizard, web-controls

I have a 2 step wizard control with a button on each step and a detailview on the second step hooked to an ObjectDataSource with select and insert methods defined. The button on the first step of the wizard hides the wizard side bar using DisplaySideBar=false and programatically navigates to the second step. The button on the second step unhides the side bar using DisplaySideBar=true and navigates back to the first step.

I have discovered that when I use the button on the first step to navigate to the second step so that the sidebar is hidden and then I attempt to insert a record into the detail view the detail view disappears completely after clicking 'insert' yet if I restart the wizard and navigate to the second step using the sidebar the insert operation goes thru correctly.

Any ideas what would cause this? Is it a Microsoft bug?

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to smell a Microsoft bug in this one...anybody else run into this kinda thing?

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one step that you want to hide the sidebar on, you can set it to the Complete step in xhtml.

```
<asp:WizardStep StepType="Complete" ...
```